# Android studio,calling RewardedAdLoadCallback jams ui

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, admob

I am using google AdMob in my android application, and  when I initialize the RewardedAdLoadCallback() the UI has a small jam, the error printed is :

E/ExtendedACodec: setParameter for extradata port definition is failed

it really doesn't matter where in the code I call my method

this is the code I wrote for the reward add callback initializer :

```
fun loadRewardAD(context : Context) {
        Constants.rewardedAd = RewardedAd(context, Constants.ADD_MOB_TEST)
        val adLoadCallback = object : RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onRewardedAdLoaded() {
                Log.v("ad", "onRewardedAdLoaded")
            }

            override fun onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.v("ad", "onRewardedAdFailedToLoad")
            }
        }
        Constants.rewardedAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build(), adLoadCallback)
    }
```

Comment: I am guessing you have already run the code without calling this method and it works fine so you are sure the problem is definitely from this function. is that right?

Comment: yes, and I just made sure and ran it again, I am sure the problem is from this function

Comment: call this function on a separate thread like this: Thread(Runnable { loadRewardedAD(this) }). if the problem is solved, it means that you are doing a lot on your UI thread so you need to consider using AsyncTask class for your heavy processes.

Comment: I thought it worked but it's still jamming the UI

Answer (score 0):

if you still haven't solved this problem, I recently did something in my project that might help you.
even when updating UI you can have async jobs.
so something like this:

```
override fun OnCreate(){

    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

        async{
        
        }
        async{
        
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

I would only put code that doesn't update UI right away in this coroutine since you may see a bit of delay on UI update. However, with loading Interstitial or Rewarded Ads, this should work just fine because they have nothing to do with the main UI.

Comment: Use runBlocking{ } if necessary.

Comment: I did not quite understand your suggestion,
the loadRewardAD() must be called from the UI thread, if not it will throw an exception
i tried to run the fun inside a MainScope() but it still James the UI for a moment.